# Owl Carousel 2: filtering items, but keep the sort order using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filtering, owl-carousel

I'm currently using Owl Carousel 2 and combining it with this filtering example to create a filter menu that when titles in the filter menu list are clicked all other items in the carousel disappear.
This works really well except that when SHOW is clicked and all items return to the carousel they are not in the order they started.

Owl Carousel 2
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html

Filter
http://www.xcast3d.com/spotlight/bootstrap-carousel-filter/

I need them to keep their sort order. Perhaps there is a better way to filter them simply using css display:none? but I'm not sure how to write this. Perhaps someone can help me alter this script or think of a better filtering solution to keep the order. Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I've found is to copy all items in the hidden div, and on filtering, empty the carousel and add again only the filtered elements in the initial order.

Working Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/TWtwt/301/

```
$('#projects-copy .project.' + cat).each(function () {
   owl.addItem($(this).clone());
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the fiddle looks great, I'm just stuck adding it to my live site.. If you could take a look at the source to see where I've gone wrong that would be amazing. You will see I've appended many of the ids with a number as there are two carousels. Here's the link: http://bit.ly/1GaL4np I'm getting this error Unexpected EOF(anonymous function).. many thanks

Comment: The quote is not the good one, probably due to an error of copy/paste. Juste replace  ’  by   '   .

Comment: That removed that error! Great. But now my version is simply hiding the entire set of items and not filtering.. Not sure what I need to change? many thanks @odupont

Comment: Change `$('#owl10 .project10')` by `$('.owl10 .project10')`, #owl10 does not exist

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to activate the filtering from an external link. I.e. click "Show me X" on an external page which then takes you to this page and filters to only show X?