# Using jQuery / Javascript to apply filter function from an external link when linked page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, filtering

This is an extension of questions I asked here: [Owl Carousel 2: filtering items, but keep the sort order using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694378/owl-carousel-2-filtering-items-but-keep-the-sort-order-using-javascript/30736844?noredirect=1#comment49564071_30736844) (hope this is ok).

I have a menu which filters items. I want the filter to be applied when clicked from and external page link. So on page X you click FilterA this directs you to page Y and filters the items to FilterA as if you had just clicked FilterA on page Y.

In the ideal world it would simply use a link such as www.example.com/pageY/#filterA.

You can see the live page [here](http://www.abstract.pinkpoliceman.com/products/).

This is the filter function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function showProjectsbyCatEur(cat) {
    var owl = $(".owl8").data('owlCarousel');

    owl.addItem('<div/>', 0);

    var nb = owl.itemsAmount;
    for (var i = 0; i < (nb - 1); i++) {
        owl.removeItem(1);
    }

    if (cat == 'all8') {
        $('#projects-copy8 .project8').each(function () {
            owl.addItem($(this).clone());
        });
    } else {
        $('#projects-copy8 .project8.' + cat).each(function () {
            owl.addItem($(this).clone());
        });
    }
    owl.removeItem(0);
}
$('.owl8 .project8').clone().appendTo($('#projects-copy8'));
$('#project-terms8 a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#project-terms8 a').removeClass('active');

    cat = $(this).attr('ID');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    showProjectsbyCatEur(cat);
});
});
```

My filter menu looks like this:

```
<div id="filter">
            <h1 class="title">Eurorack</h1>
                <div id="project-terms8">
                <ul class="filter">
                   <li class="filter"><a id="all8" class="active all" onclick="event.preventDefault();" href="#">Show All</a></li>

                   <li class="filter 3x"><a id="3x" onclick="event.preventDefault();" href="#">Clocks, Logic &amp; CV</a></li>

                    <li class="filter 2x"><a id="2x" onclick="event.preventDefault();" href="#">Filters &amp; Resonators</a></li>

                    <li class="filter 1x"><a id="1x" onclick="event.preventDefault();" href="#">Waveform Modifiers</a></li>

               </ul>
                </div>
```

So the answers so far have been helpful but not quite solve my issue. If anyone else has any advice that would be great! It seems using # is not helpful as the filter uses the id this just creates anchors down to the filter, so a `/?filter=FILTERITEM` would be best.

Alternatively a new filter system would be fine. As long as the sort order remains the same and this can be used with the URL as well as buttons.

Comment: If any of the provided solution was helpful, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a url argument with javascript and use that in the filter.

```
function getURLParameter(name) {return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
```

}

```
var filter= getParameterByName('filter');
showProjectsbyCatEur(filter);
```

then make the link something like "www.mysite.com/pageY/?filter=euro".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying to implement it, but I don't totally understand where I need to add it and how to apply it to each of the filter items.. The filters are applied by the id, so for example the link would be more like www.mysite.com/pageY/?filter=3x Do I need to add it to the existing filter? Or am I creating a new function.. sorry I'm still learning javascript.

Comment: Can anyone help me implement this answer maybe it will work as I'm stuck with the second answer?

Answer (score 3):

You have specified a preference to use an appended hashtag, so I'll answer with regard to that.

Assuming somebody makes the following request:

`http://www.abstract.pinkpoliceman.com/products/#all8`

You can, on DOM ready, retrieve the category/hashtag value and pass it to the function you're already invoking from the click event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // INSERT THE DOM READY CODE YOU ALREADY HAVE HERE

  var hash = window.location.hash;

  if(hash.length > 0)
  {
     showProjectsbyCatEur(hash.substring(hash.indexOf('#') + 1));
  }
});
```

**EXPLANATION:**

`hash.substring(hash.indexOf('#') + 1)`

This will take the hash value of '#1234' and substring it after the point at which the '#' is found. It basically removes the `#` character.

**NOTE:**

What the user submits as a hashtag is out of your control. If they don't submit `all8`, your `else` will still catch it and try to filter by it. So I suggest you rethink the conditional logic a bit to cater for 'bad' values.

**SINCE UPDATE (Request to Use Query String Parameters)**

Get the query string parameters:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// INSERT THE DOM READY CODE YOU ALREADY HAVE HERE

function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var filter = getUrlVars()['filter'];

if(filter.length > 0)
   showProjectsbyCatEur(filter);

});
```

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Url could now look like:

`http://www.abstract.pinkpoliceman.com/products/?filter=all8`

Comment: Thank you JayMee. I added this to my code. The page is updated http://www.abstract.pinkpoliceman.com/products but adding #3x for example just scrolls down to that filter link as its the id... and nothing else. Perhaps ? is better to use.

Comment: Sorry JayMee, getting this error now: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'owl.addItem'), maybe its my fault? Its breaking the carousels too

Comment: Hmmm, not sure. Have you changed anything else other than the introduction of the code I've suggested?

Comment: no nothing.. :( removing the code again makes it work as normal no errors. I'm just pasting your code straight after my existing code but before my final }); and not including your final }); (if that matters)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82869/discussion-between-pinkp-and-jaymee).

Answer (score 3):

If you want the hashes to work for links on the same page, you can use an event listener to listen for hash changes:

```
function filterByHash(){
    if(window.location.hash)//.match(/#(all8|\dx)/)
        showProjectsbyCatEur(window.location.hash.substr(1));
}

$(document).ready(filterByHash);
$(window).on('hashchange',filterByHash);
```

You can use the regex to filter out invalid hashes.

In addition, if you want to support old browsers, you can add something like this instead of the `hashchange` event listener:

```
$('#filter').on('click','a[href^=#]',function(){
    setTimeout(filterByHash,0);
});
```

The `setTimeout` pushes the function to the end of the event loop so that it's called after the hash changes.

Comment: Life saver. Was searching this for hours. My issue was angular js hash were updating the url with some delay and active menu class was setting up on correct menus.$(window).on('hashchange',filterByHash); really helped

Answer (score 2):

user3915578 wrote a very nice RegExp, but I think it would be helpful to get a better understanding of query strings as a whole.

The "#" symbol is used by browsers to anchor to certain parts of a page (like how bookmarks work on Wikipedia).

[location](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) is a built in object in browsers. The location.search property returns the part of the current URL after the "?" symbol. The query string is the proper way to pass string parameters between pages.

So the query string is the way to go. Each one of your links is going to load the page with a different value assigned to filter. The location object itself can be used to cause a redirect whenever its value changes.

```
$('#project-terms8 a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    cat = $(this).attr('ID');

    // this line causes a redirect to the same page, but with added query string
    // to redirect to a separate page, just build the new url as a string
    location = location.origin + location.pathname + '?filter=' + cat;
});
```

In your document ready function, you'll need to call your filter function on every new load, but only if filter has a value. That's where the rest of user3915578 's code should go.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // prev code

    var filter = getParameterByName('filter');
    if (filter) { showProjectsbyCatEur(filter); }
});
```

You'll have to reset the active li inside your filter function instead of your click function. Hopefully this clears up your implementation confusion.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to explain this. It's much clearer as to how and what happens but I'm still getting errors when attempting to add to my code. I think I'm confused as to which functions I'm adding to and or if I'm making new ones. I have set up a Fiddle and wondered if you would be able to show me how it should read. You will see there are two functions as I split them for the two filters. Its not a fully working fiddle just the main parts. Thanks - http://jsfiddle.net/agwmdefx/

Comment: It looks like you don't fully grasp the idea of scopes in JavaScript. jQuery uses the document ready function to execute js code as soon as the DOM is ready. But your code doesn't have to be inside the document ready function. Code at the top level of a js file will execute immediately as it's loaded onto a page. Long story short, you should only have one document ready function on each page, and you should be declaring your filter functions at the top level. I'll edit your fiddle to show what I mean.

Comment: I tried to clear things up with different function examples and comments. If anything is still confusing, let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/o8jd6xnq/2/